# am not able to find the catalog_product_save_after and catalog_product_save_before in magento

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.7, observers

hi i want to write a hook.
i made a category called BEST SELLER and one attribute called BESTSELLER(YES/NO)(default is NO)(under general). 
I want to write a hook when I assign the BEST SELLER category to any product it must change the attribute BESTSELLER to YES and when we remove product from the BEST SELLER category then it must change the BESTSELLER attribute value to NO.
But i found there is no such event exist like catalog_product_save_before and catalog_product_save_after in magento v-1.7.0.2.
any help please reply fast.

Comment: Both methods are available in 1.7 version

Answer (score 12):

### Short Answer

`catalog_product_save_before` and `catalog_product_save_after` are available AND you will not find it directly.

### Long Answer

If you are trying to search in Core files than you will not find it. Because Magento is using dynamic event dispatch for ALL the model `save_before` and `save_after`. Look in the file `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, you will find the lines:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
```

Now look in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` file. You will find the protected method eventPrefix with value `catalog_product`

```
protected $_eventPrefix      = 'catalog_product';
```

So, `$this->_eventPrefix` for Catalog Product will be `catalog_product_save_before` and `catalog_product_save_after` in Model's dispatch event.

This is applicable to all the model's save action that is extending `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.